# Force integral type parameter in Julia

Tags: types, julia

I would like to define a simple type to represent an `n`-dimensional shape, with a type parameter containing `n`.

```
julia> struct Shape{n}
           name::String
       end

julia> square = Shape{2}("square")
Shape{2}("square")

julia> cube = Shape{3}("cube")
Shape{3}("cube")

julia> dim(::Shape{n}) where n = n
dim (generic function with 1 method)

julia> dim(cube)
3
```

While this solution does work, it accepts non-integral values of `n` with no issues.

```
julia> Shape{'?'}("invalid")
Shape{'?'}("invalid")
```

My initial thought was to use a constraint on `n` in the `struct` declaration. However, neither of the ways I thought this should be accomplished seemed to work.

```
julia> struct Shape{n} where n <: Int
           name::String
       end
ERROR: syntax: invalid type signature

julia> struct Shape{n<:Int}
           name::String
       end

julia> Shape{2}("circle")
ERROR: TypeError: Shape: in n, expected n<:Int64, got Int64
```

I also tried using an inner constructor, but this did not seem to work either.

```
julia> struct Shape{n}
           Shape{n}(name) where n <: Int = new(name)
           name::String
       end

julia> Shape{2}("circle")
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Shape{2}
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Shape{2}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Stacktrace:
 [1] Shape{2}(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:24
```

I am using Julia `0.6.0-rc3.0`.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: An inner constructor works for this. What code did you use?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Apologies; it seems that I forgot to copy that code. The post has been updated.

Comment: The type of `N` is an Int, but it is not a `DataType` which is `<:Int`. You need to let it `where n` and then `@assert typeof(n) <: Int` inside the constructor.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Ah, makes sense. (Using the type assertion `n::Int` seems to be a clean way of accomplishing that, as well.) Would you mind posting your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `n` is an `Int`, but it is not a `DataType` which is `<:Int`. You need to let it where n and then `@assert typeof(n) <: Int` inside the constructor.

```
 struct Shape{n}
   name::String
   function Shape{n}(name) where n 
     @assert typeof(n) <: Int
     new(name)
   end
 end
 Shape{2}("square")
 Shape{:hi}("square")
```

Comment: Or just don't sweat it. The type `Shape{String}` technically exists but is totally useless. Similarly, `Array{12.5, ()}` exists but you can't do much with it.

Comment: Or just don't sweat it. The type `Shape{String}` technically exists but is totally useless. Similarly, `Array{12.5, ()}` exists but you can't do much with it.